# Custom JQuery Bundle, MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC form, for which I am trying to right a small piece of JQuery to determine if a check box is selected or not. I've registered my JS (Sender.js) in the bundle as such:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Sender").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Sender.js"));
    }
```

and I have it registered in my view as such:

```
<body>
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Sender")    
</body>
```

Now, two things, 1) the scripts isn't working at all, and 2) the script seems to be registering itself inside a div:

[image: rendered java script]

This is my first attempt at MVC, and i'm sure i'm missing something obvious, but can see it.

Can someone point me in the right driect to get my js file to work. Basicall, all it should do is hide or show a text box if the check box AML is selected.

**EDIT**
[image: Bundle output]

**EDIT**

Here is the entire view

```
@model BTSanctions.UserAdmin.Models.EditSenderViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Sender")    


<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Add a new Sender</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AML, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AML)
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MatchPercentage)*@
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MatchPercentage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MatchPercentage)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MatchPercentage)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: did you check the console errors? what's the specific error

Comment: hi Jorge, no error, just no JQuery. I added the alert, and that's not even firing

Comment: check the layout to see if the jquery bundle was added

Comment: Is it registered in your main _Layout.cshtml view, or a controller view?  Just wondering about those <body> tags...

Comment: @Jorge, i think this is why it's not running, the JQuery.js file is registered after the my customer call - See edit above. Which leads back to point 1) above

Comment: @markpsmith, no it's only called in this view. The body tags, were entered by myself when registering the script. If i remove i get the same result

Comment: Is at the bottom of the view i.e. the last bit of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Word "Scripts" often messed around with browser for some reason i had the same issue.
so i hit F12 to actually see if the particular js is being called. if there is

~Script/example.js   ---> 404 html error code then it means the javascript is not being rendered in the browser.

so this is what I did to get around with this problem

****************************Solution***************

1. Rename Scripts folder to Js
2. Virtaul Path name "Sender" in Jquery Bundle must **NOT** match the actual File name "Sender.Js" as doing so will make compiler confused to render the javascript.

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                       "~/Js/jquery-{version}.js"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                           "~/Js/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Senderval").Include(
                           "~/Js/Sender.js"));
   ```
3. All you scripts must be inside head tag after Jquery Bundle to be renders fist..

   <--- head--->

   ```
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Senderval")
   ```

   <----/head----->

Comment: Hi Shaz, yeah, that's what so weird - if you look at the entire page above, there is one reference to a script block/bundle, so not sure how the rest of the scripts are getting loaded into the body

Comment: I don't consider this a best approach for some reason so i always add them manually in head tag of _Layout.cshtml...use f12 an moniter your network traffic to confirm that all scripts are being loaded. most of the time scripts gets cahced in the browser . so you have to clear everthing to make sure new scripts loads up...

Comment: OK, i'll give that a bash

Comment: Right, an error this time. And one I completly understanding. $ is not recognised. this means that JQuery hasn't loaded before my customer script. Even adding it to the _Layout.cshtml view isn't preventing it from loading in the body of the page.

Comment: yes you have to load Jquery first always that why you put it in head tag to make sure this is available to all the pages/view.

Comment: My bad, i'd put it in the _ViewStart view, not _Layout :-)

Comment: Layout is the place to put all the scripts just keep in mind the order of the scripts. 
jquery will be first followed by rest of all.